# Chrome extension: Creating a temporary folder in Hard disk

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension which takes the file(s) the user want to download. Then it saves files to some temporary folder -abc- in the hard drive of the user, does some process on the file and then move all those files from temporary folder abc to default download folder of the user. How can I make a temporary folder abc in the user's hard drive with my extension and put the download files in that?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have a limited way to interact with files.  Unless you use some plugin to access the file system, Chrome only let you:

- Read files (trough XMLHttpRequest, provided your extension has file access permission)
- Download files (html way, and you don't control where the file downloads)

Comment: YoArgentino is it something you saying?
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/faq#faq-dev-08

Comment: Yasir, not, it isn't.  localstorage don't involve creating files.